# Como adicionar duas tabelas no mesmo Arraylist

Tags: java

[image: Nesta Imagem tem a tela que deve carregar os itens]Como que faço para adicionar duas tabelas no mesmo `ArrayList`?

Meu código:
{

```
public ArrayList SQLConsultagetTodos_Completo() {
    String auxtexto=edtCodigoMovimento.getText();
    int codigomovimento=Integer.parseInt(auxtexto);
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigo Movimento passado: "+auxcodigomovimento);
    String SQLConsulta_itens_dav="select itens_orc_simples.* from itens_orc_simples" +
    "inner join produto_simples on produto_simples.cd_ref=itens_orc_simples.cd_refer_pro" +
    "where itens_orc_simples.cd_movimento=?";       

    ArrayList listaitens = new ArrayList();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = Conexao.getConexao();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQLConsulta_itens_dav);
        pstmt.setInt(1,codigomovimento);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int auxquantidade=rs.getInt("qt_ite_pro");
            Double auxpreco=rs.getDouble("vl_ven_ite_pro");
            Double auxvl_custo=rs.getDouble("vl_cus_ite_pro");
            int auxcd_ref = rs.getInt("CD_REFER_PRO");
            int auxcd_usuario = rs.getInt("cd_usuario");
            int auxcd_filial = rs.getInt("cd_filial");
            int auxcd_seq_ite_pro = rs.getInt("cd_seq_ite_pro");

            VendaProdutoClassse  venpro= new VendaProdutoClassse(
                    auxquantidade,
                    auxpreco,
                    auxcd_ref,
                    auxcd_filial,
                    codigomovimento,
                    auxcd_seq_ite_pro,
                    auxcd_usuario,
                    auxvl_custo                       
            );
            listaitens.add(venpro);
         }
    } catch (SQLException erro) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro no sql, SQLConsultagetTodos_Completo:\n"
                 + erro.getMessage());
    } finally {
        Conexao.closeAll(conn);            
    }
    return listaitens;
}
```

Tenho outro método que chama esse método e carrega na tela:

```
public void ListaItensCompleto() {
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelo.addColumn("Codigo");
    modelo.addColumn("Nome");
    modelo.addColumn("Quantidade");        
    modelo.addColumn("Preco");
    ArrayList<VendaProdutoClassse> itens = SQLConsultagetTodos_Completo();

    for (VendaProdutoClassse auxitens : itens) {
        modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
            auxitens.getProduto(),
            auxitens.getQuantidade(),
            auxitens.getPreco()
        });
    }
    TabelaProdutos.setModel(modelo);
}
```

Como faço para adicionar mais essa tabela de produto no mesmo `arrayList` acima?

```
public ArrayList getTodos() {
    ArrayList listaProduto = new ArrayList();
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = Conexao.getConexao();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlTodos);
        //OBSERVE MUITO IMPORTANTE!!!!!
        //NAO DEIXAR ESPAÇOS,POIS DA ERROS DEPOIS!!!!
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Campos Inteiros
            //NÃO DEIXAR ESPAÇOS!!!!!!
            int CD_PROD = rs.getInt("CD_PROD");
            String DS_PROD = rs.getString("DS_PROD");
            int CD_GRUPO = rs.getInt("CD_GRUPO");
            int CD_SUB_GRUPO = rs.getInt("CD_SUB_GRUPO");
            int FG_ATIVO = rs.getInt("FG_ATIVO");
            int CD_COR = rs.getInt("CD_COR");
            String CD_FABRICA = rs.getString("CD_FABRICA");
            int CD_MARCA = rs.getInt("CD_MARCA");
            int CD_GP_FISCAL = rs.getInt("CD_GP_FISCAL");
            int CD_NCM_SH = rs.getInt("CD_NCM_SH");
            int CD_REF = rs.getInt("CD_REF");

            //Campos String
            //NÃO DEIXAR ESPAÇOS!!!!!!
            Produto_Simples produto = new Produto_Simples(
                    CD_PROD,
                    CD_GRUPO,
                    CD_SUB_GRUPO,
                    FG_ATIVO,
                    CD_COR,
                    CD_FABRICA,
                    CD_MARCA,
                    CD_GP_FISCAL,
                    CD_NCM_SH,
                    CD_REF,
                    DS_PROD);
            listaProduto.add(produto);
        }
    } catch (SQLException erro) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro no sql, getTodos(): \n" + erro.getMessage());
    } finally {
        Conexao.closeAll(conn);
        return listaProduto;
    }
}
```

}

Como mostra a imagem  o que preciso e que seja carregado na tela o nome do produto.

Quando eu gravo nesta tela os itens é passado como registros os dados abaixo:
    -Codigo do     Produto (auxitens.getProduto(),
    -Quantidade do Produto (auxitens.getQuantidade(),
    -Preco      do Produto (auxitens.getPreco()

```
Estes dados são gravado numa tabela de nome itens_orc_simples ->Que sao os itens do pedido

E o nome do produto deve ser carregado com o codigo do produto e deve ser buscado
da classe:
Produto_Simples
```

Que quando é carregado na tela vem desse Metodo ListaItensCompleto()

Abaixo Classe Produto_Simples:

```
public class Produto_Simples {
int CD_PROD,
    CD_GRUPO,
    CD_SUB_GRUPO,
    FG_ATIVO,
    CD_COR,
    CD_MARCA,
    CD_GP_FISCAL,
    CD_NCM_SH,
    CD_REF;
String DS_PROD, CD_FABRICA;

public Produto_Simples(int CD_PROD, int CD_GRUPO, int CD_SUB_GRUPO, int FG_ATIVO, int CD_COR, String CD_FABRICA, int CD_MARCA, int CD_GP_FISCAL, int CD_NCM_SH, int CD_REF, String DS_PROD) {
    this.CD_PROD = CD_PROD;
    this.CD_GRUPO = CD_GRUPO;
    this.CD_SUB_GRUPO = CD_SUB_GRUPO;
    this.FG_ATIVO = FG_ATIVO;
    this.CD_COR = CD_COR;
    this.CD_FABRICA = CD_FABRICA;
    this.CD_MARCA = CD_MARCA;
    this.CD_GP_FISCAL = CD_GP_FISCAL;
    this.CD_NCM_SH = CD_NCM_SH;
    this.CD_REF = CD_REF;
    this.DS_PROD = DS_PROD;
}

public int getCD_PROD() {
    return CD_PROD;
}

public void setCD_PROD(int CD_PROD) {
    this.CD_PROD = CD_PROD;
}

public int getCD_GRUPO() {
    return CD_GRUPO;
}

public void setCD_GRUPO(int CD_GRUPO) {
    this.CD_GRUPO = CD_GRUPO;
}

public int getCD_SUB_GRUPO() {
    return CD_SUB_GRUPO;
}

public void setCD_SUB_GRUPO(int CD_SUB_GRUPO) {
    this.CD_SUB_GRUPO = CD_SUB_GRUPO;
}

public int getFG_ATIVO() {
    return FG_ATIVO;
}

public void setFG_ATIVO(int FG_ATIVO) {
    this.FG_ATIVO = FG_ATIVO;
}

public int getCD_COR() {
    return CD_COR;
}

public void setCD_COR(int CD_COR) {
    this.CD_COR = CD_COR;
}

public String getCD_FABRICA() {
    return CD_FABRICA;
}

public void setCD_FABRICA(String CD_FABRICA) {
    this.CD_FABRICA = CD_FABRICA;
}

public int getCD_MARCA() {
    return CD_MARCA;
}

public void setCD_MARCA(int CD_MARCA) {
    this.CD_MARCA = CD_MARCA;
}

public int getCD_GP_FISCAL() {
    return CD_GP_FISCAL;
}

public void setCD_GP_FISCAL(int CD_GP_FISCAL) {
    this.CD_GP_FISCAL = CD_GP_FISCAL;
}

public int getCD_NCM_SH() {
    return CD_NCM_SH;
}

public void setCD_NCM_SH(int CD_NCM_SH) {
    this.CD_NCM_SH = CD_NCM_SH;
}

public int getCD_REF() {
    return CD_REF;
}

public void setCD_REF(int CD_REF) {
    this.CD_REF = CD_REF;
}

public String getDS_PROD() {
    return DS_PROD;
}

public void setDS_PROD(String DS_PROD) {
    this.DS_PROD = DS_PROD;
}
```

}

}

Comment: Depois e passado outro metodo que chama na tela estes dados:

Comment: use o "amostra de código `{}`" para formatar seu código corretamente

Comment: Qual é o valor de `sqlTodos`?

Comment: @user8014 Por favor, esclareça o que você está tentando fazer. Uma lista tem um tipo de objeto (VendaProdutoClassse) e a outra tem outro (Produto_Simples). Você realmente quer juntar os dois tipos de objetos numa lista só? Com qual intenção? Ou se não for isso, o que realmente quer fazer?

Answer (score 3):

Para você adicionar todos os elementos do ArrayList de retorno de um método de uma única vez em um ArrayList já existente use o método `addAll()`. Exemplo:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List lista = new ArrayList();
        lista.add("um");
        lista.add("dois");
        lista.addAll(maisLista());//adiciona todos os elementos no ArrayList já existente
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
    public static List maisLista() {
        List outraLista = new ArrayList();
        outraLista.add("tres");
        outraLista.add("quatro");
        return outraLista;
    }
}
```

Criei o exemplo acima para ilustrar, já que não sei qual classe que chama o seu método `getTodos()` que retorna o ArrayList que você deseja agrupar no seu primeiro ArrayList.

Referência: [ArrayList - Java SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: Creio que o problema do OP é "mais embaixo". Uma das listas tem objetos da classe `VendaProdutoClassse` e a outra da classe `Produto_Simples`. Será que ele realmente quer formar uma única lista heterogênea contendo os dois tipos de objetos? Ou ele quer exibir as duas listas lado a lado na tela? Ou alguma outra opção? Não está totalmente claro na pergunta.

Comment: Você tem razão, espero que a resposta sirva pelo menos então para o autor esclarecer a dúvida, que não está nem um pouco clara

Comment: Piovezan, O Metodo SQLTodos busca num ArrayList todos os produtos do banco de dados

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido por mim mesmo desta maneira:

```
public void ListaItensCompleto() {
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelo.addColumn("Codigo");
    modelo.addColumn("Nome");
    modelo.addColumn("Quantidade");
    modelo.addColumn("Preco");
    habilitaCampos(true);
    int aux_sequencia = 1;//Pega a sequencia
    int aux_contador = 1;   //Pega a sequencia do item
    int aux_movimento = Integer.parseInt(edtCodigoMovimento.getText());

    ArrayList<ProdutoSimples> produtosimples = SQLCarregaNomeItens();

    VendaProdutoDB venprodb = new VendaProdutoDB();
    //aqui verifica se existe item desta venda
    if (venprodb.getProdutoDaVenda(aux_movimento, aux_sequencia)) {
        aux_sequencia = 0;
        for (ProdutoSimples auxprodutosimples : produtosimples) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                auxprodutosimples.getCd_ref(),
                auxprodutosimples.getDs_prod()
            });
            TabelaProdutos.setModel(modelo);
            //Programacao do valor e quantidade
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            for (int x = aux_sequencia; x < TabelaProdutos.getRowCount(); x++) {
                try {
                    conn = Conexao.getConexao();
                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlBuscaQuantidadeEPreco);
                    pstmt.setInt(1, aux_movimento);
                    pstmt.setInt(2, aux_contador);
                    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        int aux_quantidade = rs.getInt("QT_ITE_PRO");
                        double aux_preco = rs.getDouble("VL_VEN_ITE_PRO");
                        TabelaProdutos.getModel().setValueAt(aux_quantidade, x, 2);
                        TabelaProdutos.getModel().setValueAt(aux_preco, x, 3);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException erro) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro no sql, Nome Produto Itens:\n" + erro.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    Conexao.closeAll(conn);
                }
            }
            aux_sequencia++;//Incrementa a sequencia
            aux_contador++; //Incrementa a sequencia do banco de dados               
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não existe itens nesta venda!");
        edtCodigoProduto.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Onde o método **venprodb.getProdutoDaVenda(aux_movimento, aux_sequencia)**
busca os dados da venda em relação a este item,tendo como parâmetros
o código do movimento da venda e a chave primaria do item que é o campo sequencia.

Abaixo programação do método **venprodb.getProdutoDaVenda(aux_movimento, aux_sequencia)**

```
public boolean getProdutoDaVenda(int cd_movimento, int aux_sequencia) {
    boolean existe = false;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = Conexao.getConexao();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlConsultaProdutodaVenda);
        pstmt.setInt(1, cd_movimento);
        pstmt.setInt(2, aux_sequencia);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            existe = rs.getInt("CD_SEQ_ITE_PRO") > 0;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro de SQL. getProdutoDaVenda(): \n" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        Conexao.closeAll(conn);
    }
    return existe;
}
```

**SQL sqlConsultaProdutodaVenda** é:

```
private static final String sqlConsultaProdutodaVenda
        = "SELECT                             "
        + "ITENS_ORC_SIMPLES.cd_movimento,    "
        + "ITENS_ORC_SIMPLES.CD_SEQ_ITE_PRO   "
        + "FROM                               "
        + "    ITENS_ORC_SIMPLES              "
        + "WHERE                              "
        + "ITENS_ORC_SIMPLES.cd_movimento=?   "
        + "AND                                "
        + "ITENS_ORC_SIMPLES.CD_SEQ_ITE_PRO=? "
        + "ORDER BY 2;                        ";
```

**Resumindo:**
Caso o retorno seja true no método **getProdutoDaVenda**,
eu passo os dados do produto atraves deste método:
**ArrayList produtosimples = SQLCarregaNomeItens();**
Onde **SQLCarregaNomeItens();**
está assim:

```
public ArrayList SQLCarregaNomeItens() {
    String auxtexto = edtCodigoMovimento.getText();
    int codigomovimento = Integer.parseInt(auxtexto);
    String SQLConsulta_itens_dav =
            "  select                                                           "
            + "     produto_simples.*                                           "
            + "from                                                             "
            + "     itens_orc_simples                                           "
            + "     left outer join produto_simples                         "
            + "     on produto_simples.cd_ref=itens_orc_simples.cd_refer_pro    "
            + " where                                                           "
            + "     itens_orc_simples.cd_movimento=?                            ";

    ArrayList listaProduto = new ArrayList();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = Conexao.getConexao();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQLConsulta_itens_dav);
        pstmt.setInt(1, codigomovimento);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int CD_PROD = rs.getInt("CD_PROD");
            String DS_PROD = rs.getString("DS_PROD");
            int CD_GRUPO = rs.getInt("CD_GRUPO");
            int CD_SUB_GRUPO = rs.getInt("CD_SUB_GRUPO");
            int FG_ATIVO = rs.getInt("FG_ATIVO");
            int CD_COR = rs.getInt("CD_COR");
            String CD_FABRICA = rs.getString("CD_FABRICA");
            int CD_MARCA = rs.getInt("CD_MARCA");
            int CD_GP_FISCAL = rs.getInt("CD_GP_FISCAL");
            String CD_NCM_SH = rs.getString("CD_NCM_SH");
            int CD_REF = rs.getInt("CD_REF");
            int cd_usuario = rs.getInt("cd_usuario");
            int cd_filial = rs.getInt("cd_filial");
            int cd_unidade_medida = rs.getInt("cd_unidade_medida");
            int qt_estoque = rs.getInt("qt_estoque");
            int tx_ipi = rs.getInt("tx_ipi");
            int tx_iss = rs.getInt("tx_iss");

            ProdutoSimples produto = new ProdutoSimples(
                    CD_PROD,
                    DS_PROD,
                    CD_GRUPO,
                    CD_SUB_GRUPO,
                    FG_ATIVO,
                    CD_COR,
                    CD_FABRICA,
                    CD_MARCA,
                    CD_GP_FISCAL,
                    CD_NCM_SH,
                    CD_REF,
                    cd_usuario,
                    cd_filial,
                    cd_unidade_medida,
                    qt_estoque,
                    tx_ipi,
                    tx_iss
            );
            listaProduto.add(produto);
        }
    } catch (SQLException erro) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro no sql,  SQLConsultagetTodos_Completo_NomeProduto(): \n" + erro.getMessage());
    } finally {
        Conexao.closeAll(conn);
    }
    return listaProduto;
}
```

Claro que eu poderia ter criado mais uma classe e gerenciar todos os dados
direto por ela usando um for de objetos com todos os dados do produto e da venda,
mas desta forma seria mais um arquivo pra manutenção no sistema.

Também pode ser que tenha outra forma mais "fácil" de fazer,mas no meu caso
o que me resolve o problema é isso ai.
Pois assim eu tenho apenas 2 classes para cada tabela no banco de dados,sendo:
    Tabela Produto_Simples tem a classe Produto_Simples e Produto_SimplesDB
    Tabela Itens_Orc_Simples tem a classe Itens_Orc_Simples e Itens_Orc_Simples.

**Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar.

Espero ter ajudado outras pessoas também.**